# Gnome 3 Classic Icon Placement

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions, gnome-3

I'm running Gnome 3 Classic desktop on Rocky 8. There is no longer a context-menu option to clean up the desktop. Is this option accessible, or if not is there a way to access the current icon locations and change them, preferably via scripting.